# Entity Framework collect data from multiple databases on multiple SQL Servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We are hosting several environments where users log in an start up long running activities. As a result of the multiple environments we have several SQL Server instances which each hold about 20 or so similar databases.

To collect data previously I run a query against the master db that collects builds and unions the data from each of the desired databases.

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max);

SELECT @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ' UNION ALL ', '') +
'Select ''' + QuoteName(name) + ''' as ''DatabaseName'',
@@SERVERNAME as SQLFarm,
(select top 1 Message from '+QuoteName(name)+'.dbo.LogCollection
where Message Like ''%Start: Log%'' AND Logger =''Run.''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, Runs.RunId) order by Timestamp) as ''RunLocation'',
Runs.ActivityId,
Runs.ActivityGroupId,
Runs.Started,
Runs.Finished,
Activity.DisplayName,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '+QuoteName(name)+'.dbo.[Moves] Where IsValid =1 AND RunId=Runs.RunId) As ''Moves''
FROM '+QuoteName(name)+'.dbo.[Runs]
Inner Join '+QuoteName(name)+'.dbo.Activity on
 Activity.ActivityId=Runs.ActivityId' + CHAR(13)
FROM sys.databases where name NOT LIKE '%template%' AND name LIKE '%_C%' ORDER BY name

EXEC(@sql);
```

While far too slow due to the `RunLocation` column, using EF Core and ASP.NET Core MVC, I have been able to populate this in a table into a model that gets displayed in a view.

My controller has

```
public async task<IActionResult> Index()
{
      List<testModel1> data= _context.testModel1.FromSql(sqlQuery).ToListAsync();
      return View("InexGrid",data);
}
```

I have tried adding additional `DBContext` with new connection strings but the controller constructor seems to be passed 1 through  the context. So only populates data from the first context and not the additional

How can I pull/display the live data from multiple SQL Server instances?

Comment: I would look into linked servers and SQL server views.